# Replacing $this tet on .class element with jquery

Tags: jquery

I currently have a mouseenter where I call a function that does a few different things - in this function im also looking to change the text of a certain div from $this div.

HTML:

```
//item 1
<div class="blockButton">
    <div class="blockButtonToggle">PLUS</div>
</div>

//item 2
<div class="blockButton">
    <div class="blockButtonToggle">PLUS</div>
</div>

//item 3 etc...
<div class="blockButton">
    <div class="blockButtonToggle">PLUS</div>
</div>
```

When hovering item 1,2,3 im looking to change "PLUS" text to "MINUS" for the specific block-ONLY ($this).

I tried with:

```
$('.blockButton div.blockButtonToggle').text( $(this).data('MINUS') );
```

However that didn't work - any suggestions?

FIDDLE HERE:
http://jsfiddle.net/ANRfT/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('.blockButton div.blockButtonToggle').text('MINUS');
```

More spesifically you can do:

```
$(".blockButton").on('mouseenter', textShow)
                 .on('mouseleave', textHide);

function textShow() {
    $(this).find('.blockButtonToggle').text('MINUS');
}

function textHide() {
    $(this).find('.blockButtonToggle').text('PLUS');
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ANRfT/2/)

Comment: Ended up using this one, since I like the simplified approach with the mouseenter, mouseleave.

Answer (score 1):

When you bind an eventhandler within the context of the bound function `this` will references the element the event is bound to.  You can make this a jQuery object by wrapping `$(this)`.  After wrapping the element you can then use the `find` method to get the `.blockButtonToggle` within the element.  Next you use the `html()` function, instead of `text()`, to set the innerHtml of the `.blockButtonToggle` element.

```
//MOUSEOVER
$(".blockButton").mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).find(".blockButtonToggle").html("MINUS");
});

//MOUSEOUT
$(".blockButton").mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).find(".blockButtonToggle").html("PLUS");
});
```

**Working Example** http://jsfiddle.net/ANRfT/1/

Answer (score 0):

You have quite a lot of errors. Here is the fix:

```
$(".blockButton").mouseenter(function() {
    //Calling function to show text
    textShow($(this).find(".blockButtonTips"));
})

//MOUSEOUT 
$(".blockButton").mouseleave(function() {
    //Calling function to hide text
    textHide($(this).find(".blockButtonTips"));
);

function textShow(elementId) {
    elementId.text('MINUS');
}

function textHide(elementId) {
    elementId.text('PLUS');
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ANRfT/3/)**

Comment: Hi user1479606,- it seems your example here doesnt actually replace the PLUS with MINUS, but just adds MINUS to the container?

Comment: @user1231561 I just based on your code since you use `textShow($(this).find(".blockButtonTips"));` and `.blockButtonTips` is `...`

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/ANRfT/4/

```
        $('.blockButtonToggle').hover(function () {
$(this).text('MINUS');
        });
        $('.blockButtonToggle').mouseleave(function () {
$(this).text('PlUS');
        });
```